# How to get google recaptcha Public key from drupal API?

Tags: php, drupal-7, recaptcha

I need to render the recaptcha manually and therefore I need a way to get the google recaptcha "Public key" from dupal 7 API.

It is currently in this path in the admin panel:

admin/config/spam_protection/google_recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

For anyone come across this problem, I was able to get both secret key and public key the way it was retrieved in the google_recaptcha module as shown below.

```
variable_get('google_recaptcha')['public_key']; 
variable_get('google_recaptcha')['secret_key'];
```